# How do I print a pyramid with text based on number given by user?

Tags: c, cs50

Currently stuck on creating a pyramid out of hashes (#'s) based on a number given by user input. The example for CS50 only describes how to create a square based on the number given.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = get_int("Number:\n");
    if(n>0 && n<9)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
      printf("#");
    }
  printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Expected result is to create a pyramid that is x amount of #'s wide and tall based on the input given by user.

Actual result is a square that is x amount of #'s wide and tall based on the input given by user.

Comment: Think about the problem on paper: how would you draw such a pyramid by hand? The program logic will be highly similar to the different actions and calculations you need to perform when drawing manually.

Comment: By drawing x amount of blank spaces before the # character. Which is what I am having a problem with.

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop which prints spaces until the second loop's counter (j) is less than n-i. Please see below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n, i, j, k;

    printf("Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        for (j = 0; j < n-i; j++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

        for (k =0; k <= i; k++)
        {
            printf("# ");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

} // end main function
```